# InvalidOperationException :An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid

I am a beginner with WPF, in my application i am using datatable as itemsource for WPF datagrid , this datatable is updated by multiple threads (using lock(datatable) while updating the datatable, the Exception is not consistent(not every time i run the program), i have searched a lot but none of the answers helped me to find the cause of the exception or a solution to it.

**Inner Exception:**

> {"Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):
>
> This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:3' with name 'TraceGridView'has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.
>
> The following differences were detected:  Accumulated count 2 is different from actual count 3.
>
> [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]
>
> One or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:
>
> System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator
>
> System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
>
> System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView
>
> System.Data.DataView
>
> (The starred sources are considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)
>
> The most common causes are (a) changing the collection or its Count without raising a corresponding event, and
>
> (b) raising an event with an incorrect index or item parameter.
>
> The exception's stack trace describes how the inconsistencies were detected, not how they occurred.
>
> To get a more timely exception, set the attached property 'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the generator to value 'High' and rerun the scenario.
>
> One way to do this is to run a command similar to the following:
>
> System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator,System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High)from the Immediate window.
>
> This causes the detection logic to run after every CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the application."}

**Stack Trace:**

```
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Verify()
at
System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator& generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider, IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem, Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Boolean& computedAreContainersUniformlySized, IList& items, Object& item, IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged, Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport, VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit& cacheUnit, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double& firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size& stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize, Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean& mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure, Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean& hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean& hasVirtualizingChildren)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1& previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Boolean remeasure)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at GUI_WPF_.App.Main() in d:\work\CANTrackRepo2\GUI(WPF)\obj\Release\App.g.cs:line 0
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**Here is code where i update the DataGrid:**

```
private void UpdateDataGridView(DataTable dt)
{
    if (this.TraceGridView.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            this.TraceGridView.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            this.TraceGridView.Items.Refresh();
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        SetUpdateTraceDataGridCallBack d = new SetUpdateTraceDataGridCallBack(UpdateDataGridView);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { dt });
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the exception/issue, but I do know you should follow MVVM.

Comment: You don't need to call BeginInvoke when CheckAccess returned true. Just call `ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;` directly, no need for `Items.Refresh()`.

Comment: When i remove `Items.Refresh()` nothing appears on the Datagrid and also when i removed `BeginInvoke()` it didn't solve it.